# Function name resolution in a lambda that captures _this_

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void f()
{
    std::cout << "Called ::f()" << std::endl;
}

struct S
{
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Called S::f()" << std::endl;
    }

    void oops()
    {
        [this](){ f(); }(); // calls the wrong function
    }
};

int main()
{
    S().oops();
    return 0;
}
```

(http://ideone.com/w7nyb)

VS2010 calls `::f()` but GCC & VS2012 calls `S::f()`. To me it seems that VS2012 is correct.

Which function should be called according to the standard?

Comment: GCC 4.7.2 also calls `S::f()` – this was probably a regression in GCC 4.6.x (and I wouldn't expect sane behavior out of VC++ _2010_).

Comment: GCC 4.7.1 also prints `S::f()`.

Comment: When compiled with Visual C++ 2012, `::f()` is not called.  `S::f()` is called, which is the correct behavior.  (When compiled with Visual C++ 2010 SP1, `::f()` _is_ called, but you expressly call out Visual C++ 2012 as having incorrect behavior, which is not true.)

Comment: @James: yes, you're right. When I run the standalone example from the question in VS2012, it calls `S::f()`. However, in my code where `S().oops()` is called inside a `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE`, it calls the global function instead.

Comment: Can you produce a standalone example that demonstrates the problem?  That sounds like it might, perhaps, be a bug.

Comment: It turned out to be a typo in my code. Both VS2012 & GCC 4.6 do the right thing. I'll vote to close the question.

Comment: No need to close the question.  "Why do [these older compilers] not do the right thing?" is a perfectly valid question.  You might just reword the second to last sentence to correct which compilers do what.

Comment: The only older compiler that doesn't do the right thing that I'm aware of is VS2010. I'll rephrase the question to state that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`S::f()` should be called.  C++11 §5.1.2/7 states:

> The *lambda-expression*'s *compound-statement* yields the *function-body* of the function call operator, but for purposes of name lookup, determining the type and value of `this` and transforming *id-expressions* referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using `(*this)`, the *compound-statement* is considered in the context of the *lambda-expression*.

The important part here is that "for purposes of name lookup,... the *compound-statement* is considered in the context of the *lambda-expression*."  Since there is no `f` declared locally in the lambda block, it is looked up just as it would be looked up if it was referred to directly from the body of `oops`.  Therefore, the member function is found.

---

Note that recent versions of Visual C++ and gcc both have the correct behavior (including Visual C++ 2012 and gcc 4.7.2).  Older versions may exhibit incorrect behavior because the lambda specification was overhauled in the second half of 2009 (see [n2927:  New wording for C++0x Lambdas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf) [PDF]).  Remember that before C++11 was finalized, the specification was a moving target, and older compilers are likely to implement different revisions of the specification.  Even now, many implementers are still working to catch up to the final specification.

Comment: And to clarify, those lookups rules are the same regardless of capture -- although of course calling a non-static member function without capturing `this` is an error, but for different reasons. Consider however a lambda containing e.g. `using foo = decltype(f());`.